# Foundation 6 Slider using disabled with a set value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, zurb-foundation

I have been racking my brain trying to figure this one out.  I have a large amount of these bars through out my site. Some of the bars show a default value but can not be changed. The site is currently running foundation 5 and the bars work fine but when converting to 6 the system fails. The following code is their default sample which displays with an initial value.

```
<div class="slider" data-slider data-initial-start="50" data-end="200">
  <span class="slider-handle"  data-slider-handle role="slider" tabindex="1"></span>
  <span class="slider-fill" data-slider-fill></span>
  <input type="hidden">
</div>
```

Now we take the code and simply add the disabled class to the slider.  When we do this it disables the slider but moves the slider back to 0.

```
<div class="slider disabled" data-slider data-initial-start="50" data-end="200">
  <span class="slider-handle"  data-slider-handle role="slider" tabindex="1"></span>
  <span class="slider-fill" data-slider-fill></span>
  <input type="hidden">
</div>
```

Has anyone run into this issue and found a solution. I simply want to lock the value to the initial start value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing everything I could think of and working with many people I finally came up with a solution. For those looking for an answer to this please enjoy the code below.

```
$('.sliderDisabled').on('moved.zf.slider',function(){
    $(this).addClass('disabled');
});
```

Simply add the class sliderDisabled to your slider.  This code will disable the slider after the bar handle moves.

Comment: You could also add an id to a slider and refer to the specific id if you wanted to disable some individual sliders vs. all with the added classname (same outcome just different way of getting there).

I find it interesting that there is no currently known way of having the slider start at the data-initial-start position instead of having to go from the lower limit to it, taking up all those resources for coolness sake.